# issue installing fedora 19

Tags: linux, fedora, system-installation

I wanted to install Fedora 19 with my Windows 7 (dual boot) but when I go through the installation process it only shows my harddrive (not partitions) and says that there is 37 gig available for u an 17 mb available for us and says that there is not enough space on my hard drive. I have a 500 gig hard drive and three ntfs partitions with a LOT of free space should i resize one partition and leave the free space unallocated and then try to install fedora?

Comment: resize one partition, you don't install linux on windows filesystem ( unless under a vm AFAIK ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have unallocated space on your hard drive in which to install Fedora. Also keep in mind the 4 primary or 3 primary + 1 extended partition limit for drives using the legacy partition scheme, since you say you already have 3 partitions on your disk.

Comment: tnx that was real helpful just one more questions how can i know that how many partitions are supported in my legacy partition scheme i have an asus n43jq laptop i googled it but i didn't find anything

Comment: and another question can't i convert one of my partitions to fat32 and then try to install it on that one leaving the rest of hard untouched?

Comment: Both of those are answered in my answer.

Comment: so in my situation (having 3 partitions) there shouldn't be any problems should be?
sry im just nervous about my hard i can't afford buying a new one

Comment: Are they all primary partitions?

Comment: I think so how can i find out?

Comment: Check the drive management tool in Windows.

Comment: yes theyre all primary

Comment: So then you'll have to install Linux on multiple logical drives, and install the bootloader to the MBR.

Comment: is there any tutorial for that im a complete noob to this stuff like partitioning and hardware

Comment: Nothing that I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: alright i google it
thanks for ur help you've been a greeeeat help!

Comment: hey now i have one 40GB primary partition with ext4 file system can i install fedora on it?

Comment: i can't make another partition for swap is that ok?

Comment: You don't need to install Fedora to a primary partition.

Comment: i don't know why i was thinking that linux partition should be primary i read a LOT online and now im creating 3 logicals 1 for /boot on e for / and one for swap hopefully this solves my problem.

Comment: hey Ignacio thanks for your help I made two logicals for /root and swap and one primary for /boot and installed fedora. everything works perfect now, dual boot is working too